# To remove double quotation in string array

Tags: asp.net

In the below code i have a string array which holds values i want to remove double quotion in the array and display values like 1,2,3,4,5.Pls help me to do this.

```
DataSet Stock = Chart.ChartCurrentStock(LocationID);

List<string> StockDetails = new List<string>();

foreach (DataRow row in Stock.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    StockDetails.Add(row["CurrentStock"].ToString());
}

string[] Stocks = StockDetails.ToArray();
```

Comment: _What_ is your input and _HOW_ do you want the output to be. supply an example

Comment: @Royi Namir It is like array value [0]="12" [1] ="14" it should be 12,14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your code sample but:  ( *how it relates?*)

If you have a string array and you want one final single string separated with `","` :

```
string[] g = new string[]{"1","2","3"};
var s=string.Join(",",g);
Console.WriteLine (s); // "1,2,3"
```

Comment: I want to remove first and last double quotation it should be 1,2,3 not "1,2,3"